# MSAL in Angular - no_account_error: No account object provided to acquireTokenSilent

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I've implemented an Azure AD login using the MSAL library on a Web App running Angular 11 and .NET Core 2.2.
The login seems to work fine, but I couldn't find any reliable info on how to handle a 401 (unauthorized) HTTP error due to an expired token.
Apparently I have to call acquireTokenSilent after having processed an interactive login, but when I do this I'm getting the following error:

> Error retrieving access token: BrowserAuthError: no_account_error: No
> account object provided to acquireTokenSilent and no active account
> has been set. Please call setActiveAccount or provide an account on
> the request.

Where can I find the setActiveAccount method? I don't see it anywhere in the MsalService Class. Also I believe the library should set the account to active after a successful login.

I'm testing this scenario by returning a 401 Error from my API after the user logged in, to trigger the acquireTokenSilent call.

Here's the code from the Interceptor that handles the 401 Error:

```
  return next.handle(authReq).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => {
                    
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {                
            
            if(this._settings.msalAuthentication) {
                console.log("Attempting to get new MSAL access token: "+this._settings.msalAuthentication.scopes);
                this._msal.acquireTokenSilent({scopes: this._settings.msalAuthentication.scopes})
                    .subscribe(result => {                            
                        console.log("received new MSAL token: "+result);
                      this._dataService.handleMsalAuthenticationResult(result);                              
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log("Error retrieving access token: "+error);
                    });
                return EMPTY;
            }
```

The msalAuthentication object contains the result of the initial login, including the token, user info and scopes. I don't think the user should see a popup every time the token expires.
Help would be appreciated.